# Loop children while shifting skips

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, z-index, children

I'm stuck with this code I created. What it does is that it loops through all the children in a class and then checks if it has the priority property set to 1. When the the priority is 1 it gets added to the end of the childList. The problem I am having is that when it finds an object with priority 1 it skips the next object. This is because it moves the object to the end, meaning that the whole array moves one position to the left so it skips the next object because it thinks it already checked it!

```
for (var j:int = 0; j < this.numChildren; j++) 
    {
        var tempObject:Object = this.getChildAt(j);
        if (tempObject._priority == 1)
        {
            var indexofnew:Number = this.getChildIndex(tempObject as DisplayObject);
            this.setChildIndex(this.getChildAt(indexofnew),this.numChildren-1); 
        }
```

I have run into a complete wall on how to solve this. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You mean that it loops through all the children on the display list of a given DisplayObject, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you move the position of a given child on the display list to the end of the list, the index of the other children below it will decrement.

the best approach could be to iterate through the loop backwards as the only changes to the child indexes would be on the DisplayObjects already processed.

```
for (var j:int = numChildren-1; J >= 0; j--) 
{
        var tempObject:Object = this.getChildAt(j);
        if (tempObject._priority == 1)
        {
            var indexofnew:Number = this.getChildIndex(tempObject as DisplayObject);
            this.setChildIndex(this.getChildAt(indexofnew),this.numChildren-1); 
        } 
}
```

Comment: Like I commented on Chad's solution this code works too but it creates a infinite loop.

Comment: did you try this version ? I updated my answer. This should not result in a infinite loop, it's a reverse loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a while loop instead. This way your loop will only increment if there is NOT a match. On a match it will stay the same.

```
var j = 0;
while(j < this.numChildren) {
    var tempObject:Object = this.getChildAt(j);
    if(tempObject._priority == 1) {
        var indexofnew:Number = this.getChildIndex(tempObject as DisplayObject);
        trace(indexofnew+"n");
        this.setChildIndex(this.getChildAt(indexofnew),this.numChildren-1); 
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works but unfortunately it becomes and infinite loop towards the end. Since the last few objects are matches it will keep iterating.

Comment: This answer is similar to my initial thoughts, but it will result in a endless loop, because if the last child's `_priority == 1` then it won't iterate `j`, so `j' will always be lower than `numChildren` in that case.